# Java MigLayout - help getting it up and running

Tags: java, miglayout

I've spent all night trying to accomplish what I thought would be a simple task.

I would like to use the latest version of [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/), I believe that is 5.1 but at this point I would settle for 4.2, for a project I'm doing for school.

It seems that I can not find the correct file (.jar) to download because everything I think is the correct one never works when I use it in my project. FYI I am using NetBeans 8.1 and I know how to go into the project properties and add the .jar file as a library.

It seems the closet I've managed to get to a working library turned out to be empty classes. It had all the class names but all the functionality stripped out. I guess that was a demo library? Snapshot?

I have searched all night long for some help installing/ initializing MigLayout in my project and could not find a single video or document that could be remotely called a tutorial on how to get MigLayout up and running. Can anyone help me out? I need to be spoon feed on this ONE step. Once I have a working library I'm good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution would be to use a Dependency Management System like Maven or Ivy. But also you are not using such a thing they can help to find the correct jars:
[Maven Repo for Miglayout](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cmiglayout). The pom.xml files could tell you which dependencies you also need.

I guess you are writing a Swing application and so you need the swing version:
[Miglayout Swing](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/miglayout/miglayout-swing/5.0/miglayout-swing-5.0.jar) which depends on the [Miglayout Core](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/miglayout/miglayout-core/5.0/miglayout-core-5.0.jar) (see pom.xml of the Swing artifact). So add this two jar files to your project and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had been downloading from the Maven repo but just realized I had some errors in my own code I was using to test. The proper libraries and my fixed code did the trick.